# How do I create a list of dictionaries based on the same id?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I've got three lists below:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, word: "a", wordId: "05144502" },
  { id: 1, word: "b", wordId: "09309701" },
  { id: 2, word: "c", wordId: "05221504" },
  { id: 2, word: "d", wordId: "05221504" },
];
```

How can combine these three lists to this:

```js
[
  {
    1: [
      { word: "a", wordId: "05144502" },
      { word: "b", wordId: "09309701" },
    ],
  },
  {
    2: [
      { word: "c", wordId: "05221504" },
      { word: "d", wordId: "05221504" },
    ],
  },
]
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: Your expected output seems overly complex,.  Why not just -> `{1: [{word:...},{word:...}], 2:[{word:...},{word:...}]}`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array to hold your dictionary, loop over `data` and for each id add the words in a separate array. Something like this:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, word: "a", wordId: "05144502" },
  { id: 1, word: "b", wordId: "09309701" },
  { id: 2, word: "c", wordId: "05221504" },
  { id: 2, word: "d", wordId: "05221504" },
];

const dictionary = [];
const idToIndexMap = {};

data.forEach(rec => {
    if(idToIndexMap[rec.id] !== undefined) {
        dictionary[idToIndexMap[rec.id]][rec.id].push({word: rec.word, wordId: rec.wordId});
    } else {
        dictionary.push({[rec.id]: [{word: rec.word, wordId: rec.wordId}] });
        idToIndexMap[rec.id] = dictionary.length - 1;
    }
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(dictionary));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const data = [
      { id: 1, word: 'a', wordId: '05144502' },
      { id: 1, word: 'b', wordId: '09309701' },
      { id: 2, word: 'c', wordId: '05221504' },
      { id: 2, word: 'd', wordId: '05221504' },
    ];

    const dic: { [key: number]: { id: number; word: string; wordId: string }[] } = {};

    for (const v of data) {
      dic[v.id] = [...(dic[v.id] || []), v];
    }
```

or use [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash)

```
    const data = [
      { id: 1, word: 'a', wordId: '05144502' },
      { id: 1, word: 'b', wordId: '09309701' },
      { id: 2, word: 'c', wordId: '05221504' },
      { id: 2, word: 'd', wordId: '05221504' },
    ];
    const result = _.groupBy(data, 'id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper array to make sure that you can easily find the items:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, word: "a", wordId: "05144502" },
  { id: 1, word: "b", wordId: "09309701" },
  { id: 2, word: "c", wordId: "05221504" },
  { id: 2, word: "d", wordId: "05221504" },
];

let output = [];
let objects = {};
for (let item of data) {
    let obj = {};
    for (let key in item) {
        if (key !== "id") obj[key] = item[key];
    }
    if (!objects[item.id]) {
        let wrapper = {
            [item.id]: [obj]
        };
        objects[item.id] = wrapper;
        output.push(objects[item.id]);
    } else {
        objects[item.id][item.id].push(obj);
    }
}

console.log(output);
```